# Possible to run Express/React/Node application on Heroku w/ remote connection to Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, heroku

I'm running it fine locally in Node.js using Sequelize/Tedious. This is a test application so database security not required. If not supported on Heroku, any other services that do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!! I suspected something was up with my Create-React-App/Express.js boilerplate so I re-created from scratch and then brought over all of my React components. This time I also made sure I had the latest version of Create-React-App too - I was running a much older version. Seems like the older version wasn't playing well with the newer node packages (express, sequelize, tedious, etc.). All is well now.